# Unparametrized lightlike geodesics are invariant under conformal change. How does the parametrization change?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold and $\gamma: I \rightarrow M$ be a lightlike geodesic with $0 \in I$.
Let $\hat{g}=e^{2 \sigma} g$ be a conformally equivalent metric.
Maybe having to make $I$ a bit smaller, say $\tilde{I} \subset I$, there exists some change of coordinates $\tau: J \rightarrow \tilde{I}$, such that $\gamma \circ \tau$ is a geodesic with respect to $\hat{g}$ and has the same 1-jet, i.e. $\gamma(0)=\gamma \circ \tau (0)$ and $\gamma'(0)=(\gamma \circ \tau)' (0)$.

> Question:
>   What reparametrizations can possibly occur here?

Suggested answer:
All intervals $J \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $0 \in J$ and all smooth, strictly monotonously increasing maps $\tau: J \rightarrow I$ can appear as a change of coordinates.

Let $\nabla$ and $\hat{\nabla}$ be the Levi-Civita connections for $g$ and $\hat{g}$ respectively.
We have the formula

$\hat{\nabla}_X Y = \nabla_X Y + d\sigma (X) Y+ d\sigma (Y) X- g(X,Y) grad \sigma$.

This implies
$$
\begin{split}
&\hat{\nabla}_{(\gamma \circ \tau)'(s)} (\gamma \circ \tau)'
\\&=\nabla_{(\gamma \circ \tau)'(s)} (\gamma \circ \tau)' + 2 d \sigma((\gamma \circ \tau)'(s)) \cdot (\gamma \circ \tau)'(s) - \| (\gamma \circ \tau)'(s) \| grad \sigma
\\&=\nabla_{(\gamma \circ \tau)'(s)} (\gamma \circ \tau)' + 2 d \sigma((\gamma \circ \tau)'(s)) \cdot (\gamma \circ \tau)'(s)
\\&=\frac{\tau ''(s)}{\tau'(s)} \cdot (\gamma \circ \tau)'(s) + 2 d \sigma((\gamma \circ \tau)'(s)) \cdot (\gamma \circ \tau)'(s).
\end{split}
$$

$\gamma \circ \tau$ is a geodesic if and only if above term vanishes, i.e. if and only if $\frac{\tau''(s)}{\tau'(s)}+2 d \sigma ( (\gamma \circ \tau)'(s))=0$ for all $s \in J$.
This is a second-order ODE.
Because the the reparametrization should leave the 1-jet invariant, we have the initial condition $\tau(0)=0$ and $\tau'(0)=1$.
By the Picard-Lindelöf theorem a locally unique solution $\tau : J \rightarrow \tilde{I}$ exists, maybe making $\tilde{I}$ again a bit smaller.
The solution satisfies

$\tau(s)=\int_0^s e^{-2 \sigma(\gamma \circ \tau (s))} ds$.

We made $\tilde{I}$ sufficiently small, so that $\gamma$ is injective.
Hence we may (smoothly) choose arbitrary positive values for $\sigma$ along $\gamma$.

Can we receive any possible monotonously increasing (smooth) function $\tau$ through that?
I looks like it, but I cannot put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any smooth reparametrization can be obtained by a smooth conformal change of the metric, provided that the geodesic does not intersect itself.
Assuming no self-intersections, the question is whether one can choose $\alpha:=\sigma\circ\gamma$ (the conformal factor along the geodesic) so that
$$
\frac{\tau''(s)}{\tau'(s)}+2 d \sigma ( (\gamma \circ \tau)'(s))=0.
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{d}{ds}[\log(\tau'(s))+2(\alpha \circ \tau)(s)]=0,
$$
so that $\log(\tau'(s))+2(\alpha \circ \tau)(s)$ is a constant $c$.
Evaluating at $s=0$ gives
$$
c
=
\log(\tau'(0))+2(\alpha \circ \tau)(0)
=
2\alpha(0).
$$
Now that we have
$$
\log(\tau'(s))+2(\alpha \circ \tau)(s)=2\alpha(0)
$$
for all $s$, we can plug in $s=\tau^{-1}(t)$ to get
$$
\alpha(t)=\alpha(0)-\frac12\log(\tau'(\tau^{-1}(t))).
$$
Given any change of parameter $\tau$ and any initial $\alpha(0)$, this gives a method to find the corresponding $\alpha$.